# What input data file should be given to Stanford Open Information Extraction?

Tags: stanford-nlp

command used:  `java -mx1g -cp stanford-openie.jar:stanford-openie-models.jar edu.stanford.nlp.naturalli.OpenIE  /path/to/file1  /path/to/file2`
I am trying to use the code given here (http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/openie.html#Questions) for slot filling.
So the above command is used to generate relation triples for the sentence i type on command line. I want to analyse everything done in this paper by @Gabor Angeli :Leveraging Linguistic Structure For Open Domain Information
Extraction.
Kindly help me with this.

Comment: I'm unclear what the question is. Does the command not work to give you triples, or is the issue converting those triples to slot fills? For the latter, I recommend simply hand-coding a mapping, and searching for NER span overlaps.

Comment: @GaborAngeli Thank you Sir! Can you please elaborate on 'converting the generated triples to slot fills'? I shall be grateful.